# Working with Pandas DataFrame / Sorting

Tags: python, excel, sorting, pandas

I'm working with a big dataset within Excel in which I'm trying to sort a number by top 25 per index value.

The datasite looks like this:

[image: Example]

The Final PAC ID is the company number and changes (this does not show in the given data). The PAC contribution is the number I want to sort by.

So for example, there will be 50 contributions done by company C00003590, to different candidates with amount 'PAC contribution', I would like to sort the top 25 contributions done per company.

I've tried working with dictionaries, creating a dictionary for each company and adding in the candidate numbers as a string key, and the contribution as a value.

The code I have so far is the following (this might be the completely wrong way to go about it though):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel('Test2.xlsx')

dict_company = {}
k1 = str(df1['Final PAC ID'])
k2 = str(df1['Candidate ID'])

for each in range(0,100):
    dict_company[k1)[each]] = {}
    dict_company[k1)[each]] = k2[each]
    if each % 50 == 0:
        print(each)

print(dict_company)

for each in range(0,100):
    dict_company[k1][k2][each] = round(float(k1[each]))
    if each % 50:
        print(each)

print(dict_company)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nlargest.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby('Final PAC ID')['PAC contribution'].nlargest(50)
```

If need all columns:

```
cols = df.columns[~df.columns.isin(['PAC contribution','Final PAC ID'])].tolist()
df1 = df.set_index(cols)
         .groupby('Final PAC ID')['PAC contribution']
         .nlargest(50)
         .reset_index()
```

Another solution (can be slowier):

```
df1 = df.sort_values('PAC contribution', ascending=False).groupby('Final PAC ID').head(50)
```

Last save to excel by [`to_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html):

```
df1.to_excel('filename.xlsx')
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed!
How would I go about saving this back to the excel file though? it does not seem to change the dataframe itself if I remove the print command.

Comment: Ah right, I tried doing the same thing but isntead of making a new dataframe I tried to override the current dataframe. Thank you very much for the answer though, helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby('Final PAC ID').head(50).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) in conjunction with a dictionary comprehension here. The `result` is a dictionary containing your company names as keys and the sub dataframes with top 25 payments as values:

```
def aggregate(sub_df):
    return sub_df.sort_values('PAC contribution', ascending=False).head(25)

grouped = df.groupby('Final PAC ID')
results = {company: aggregate(sub_df)
           for company, sub_df in grouped}
```